# chart.js chart failing to render

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to render out this chart to test and see if I can render charts on my website, later I will also, use Django models to get dynamic data, but before I can do that this thing is not rendering. I have tried many things, but I can hardly figure out the problem.

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="myChart" width ="400" height = "400"> </canvas>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var endpoint = "/api/networthchart/data/"
    
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url : endpoint,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(errordata){
      console.log(errordata)
    },
  })

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  
})
</script>
```

HTML:
I think my import of the needed CDNs is not proper, take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong.

main.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Stock Trading Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "/css/main.css"%}">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
   
    {% include "accounts/navbar.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    
    </body>

</html>
```

chart.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %} 
{% block content %}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var endpoint : "/api/networthchart/data/"
    
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(errordata){
      console.log(errordata)
    },
  })

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  
})
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried the proposed solution, it works on codepen, but I think there is something wrong with my imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error. Change `url = endpoint` to `url: endpoint` :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var endpoint = "/api/networthchart/data/"
    
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(errordata){
      console.log(errordata)
    },
  })

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  
})
```

Comment: it still doesn't render, I mean thank you for catching that blunder, but I am not even using that right now, and it's still not rendering, could you please take a look at it again?

Comment: @VardhanMahajan i dont have an issue with my example. Here is the codepen with the same code i posted https://codepen.io/yalcinkilic/pen/YzGmZKJ

Comment: oh, then maybe I am doing something wrong. thank you, buddy, I will try and figure it out lol.

Comment: @VardhanMahajan Your need jquery and chart.js for this check your dev tools

Comment: yep, thank dude. Appreciate it, maybe thats where I am going wrong :)

Comment: I have tried the proposed solution, it works on codepen, but I think there is something wrong with my imports. could you take another look, I have put my HTML. I have having troble understanding where my imports are going wrong, could you give it a look

Comment: Where is your canvas element with the id myChart?

Comment: ohh, its there, I forgot to add it my bad, give me 1sec

Comment: @VardhanMahajan make sure you have var endpoint = "/api/networthchart/data/"; and not var endpoint : "/api/networthchart/data/"; for the variable declaration. And you problem is that your script in chart.html is in your html file so its excecuted before the js files in your head are loaded. Put the script in a seperate js file and load it equal to the others in your head section. Just put your canvas element in your body

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, I didnt know that was a thing, okay, thanks dude, This has to be it! Thank you sooo much for the help buddy! You are a kind person, saved me hours of emotional pain.

Comment: It's working now, I commented out the ajax part and now it's working! POG

Comment: @VardhanMahajan happy to hear that :)